# convert messages in transit from UUEncode to MIME

Tags: exchange, smtp, iphone, activesync

I have a third-party app that generates emails in UUEncode format with PDF attachments. [The PDF attachments are unreadable](https://serverfault.com/questions/398745/some-pdfs-to-iphones-via-activesync-are-corrupt) because [iPhones don't understand UUEencode apparently](https://serverfault.com/questions/386326/uuencoded-mail-attachments-display-as-binary-code).

I don't see any settings anywhere in Exchange 2010 to make the Exchange server convert it.

Are there any open source SMTP servers that will do this conversion? I'd be willing to send this server's messages through another SMTP server to do the conversion before it's send to Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a plug-in for qpsmtpd called tnef2mime. It was originally designed to convert Microsoft's TNEF (winmail.dat) attachments to MIME, but it also converts UUEncoded messages. I couldn't find a canonical source for this plugin, but [SME Server](http://wiki.contribs.org/Main_Page) keeps [the plugin in their distribution](http://distro.ibiblio.org/pub/linux/distributions/smeserver/releases/8/smeos/x86_64/SME/smeserver-qpsmtpd-2.2.0-13.el5.sme.noarch.rpm) and the bug database implies that people are using it recently.

So I added qpsmtpd to a small Ubuntu server I'm using for other purposes, extracted tnef2ime from the RPM, enabled it as a plugin, and I am now sending my problematic SMTP clients through this box first.